# Azure Data factory - Data flow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I need to handle Minus operation in Azure Data factory - Data flows. Is this feature supported in Data flow or is there any work around for this. Pls provide the inputs. I know it can be done using SP activity or Databricks transformation activity or in other ways as well, but want to know if it can be done using Data flows itself in ADF. I have two tables one having yesterday data and another having today data, in Databases using minus i can find the differences between two tables. For eg In Table A a record exists as A, 123 and Table B record exists as A, 456. When i do a minus operation it will fetch this record.

Comment: You could use data flow DerivedColumn to do the Minus operation between the two table. What's the sink dataset ? Does the table A and table B have the same schema and the same rows?

Comment: yes both Table A and B will have same schema..

Comment: what‘s your Sink dataset or the destination dataset to store the minus result? Please give us more details!

Comment: Sink will be Azure SQL DWH

Answer (score 1):

You could put that query in the Source query in any Source transformation in ADF Data Flows. Just use EXCEPT rather than MINUS:

select * from dbo.ProdFromSales2 except select * from dbo.DimProducts

Answer (score 0):

You could use data flow DerivedColumn to do the Minus operation between the two table.

For example, I create two tables for the test: `test7` and `test8`:
[image]

**Data flow overview**:

[image]

**Join settings and data preivew**:

[image]

**DerivedColumn settings and data preview:**
[image]
[image]

**Sink settings, mappings:**
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Leon Yue for detailed explanation..I'm looking for minus operation which happens in a query language not this minus..In SQL Server I could do a minus query as below Select * from a MINUS Select * from b. I need to do this operation using Data flow. Hope its clear

Comment: @ArunS Yeah, I tested again like you want. Unfortunately, both `Select * from a MINUS Select * from b` or  `Select * from a except Select * from b` can not get the result you want  in Data Flow or Copy Active.  Any other suggestions, you may create a stored proc  to do the minus operation in your ADW,  using copy active to copy the data from table a, then call the stored proc in sink/destination. You must test by yourself.

Comment: I can use exists clause with comparing all the columns.in this case i need to write all the columns comparision..was looking for any better approach than this..